# Get Android 7 do not disturb features back?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, do-not-disturb

Do not disturb in Android 8 is now awful

1. No way to tell it to Do Not Disturb for an hour
2. No way to tell it to turn off DND after an alarm goes off (unless you specify a rule sets your phone to DND at a specific time every single night)

Any way to get the DND of Android 7 back? I used these features all the time. I have a Pixel XL

Comment: I have the same options on my Nexus 6P as I did on Nougat. Have you tried clicking the 'Do not disturb' text in the notification panel? I get the 1 hour option and (when within 12 hours of an alarm) the option to turn off at next alarm.

Comment: @bmdixon Oh I see it now, they just hid it.  Put your response as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same options on my Nexus 6P as I did on Nougat however, they are accessed slightly differently. If you click the 'Do not disturb' text in the notification panel you should see the options you're after. I get the 1 hour option and (when within 12 hours of an alarm) the option to turn off at next alarm.

[image]
[image]

[This article](https://arstechnica.co.uk/gadgets/2017/09/android-8-oreo-review/3/#h1) on Ars Technica demonstrates a few other changes to the quick settings pane (see image below too).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was a "nerve silencer" (from that really disturbing DND change, if you get the play on words). Are you aware of any way to switch that around, to avoid having to open the entire tile section? Somehow the man was right saying "Most changes today focus on replacing what works with what sounds good". And I bet the "old variant" covers more "daily need" than those rule sets which probably only few use, if at all…

Answer (score 0):

Found an app called Timed Silent, which takes care of part 1. Also I just noticed that you can snooze notifications in Google Hangouts (shutting Hangouts up is mostly what I used the timed DND for). So that takes care of part 1

Answer (score 0):

On Android 11 this is still  an issue. A long click on DND icon will open up a settings dialog. click Advanced -> Duration for quick settings -> Ask every time.

[image]